# Arabic letters width' problem in OpenALPR training sheet generation

Tags: ocr, tesseract, openalpr

I have created numbers and letters tiles and organized them with a max height of 40px. But when I run `openalpr-utils-prepcharsfortraining` I get this result:

[image]

As you can see the arabic letters are having difficult times. Here are the letters in the original form to compare versus the numbers:

[image]

[image]

When I checked the [source code](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/src/misc_utilities/prepcharsfortraining.cpp), I found out that the tools resizes the images to 40px height by default, how to fix this?

What should I do? Please help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... Just added `--tile_width 70` to the command and bam! job done!